# Drupal 6: How can i create a content typed 'white paper'?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-webform

[Drupal 6] By installing [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) i can create a content typed 'webform' but how can i create a content typed 'white paper'? I didn't find any module named so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CCK. Didn't you google "Custom Content Type Drupal"?